# Simplifying a line before rendering on chart in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I am trying to plot data collected live from bee hives. We plan to collect data every 5 minutes, so in a year there will be on the order of 100,000 data points. I want to set up a chart to plot the data, and have new data enter the chart everytime the database changes (using Meteor).

I have a simple mockup at [datacomb.meteor.com](http://datacomb.meteor.com) These charts were made using dc.js, a d3 wrapper.

Is there a way to use the topojson.simplify (http://bost.ocks.org/mike/simplify/) functionality to pre-process the lines and reduce the number of points rendered? Has a more general simplification method been integrated into d3?

Comment: I would try binning the data more (by hour or by day) before you graph it.

Comment: I might try this for now. This would work for a while, but I would still like a more general solution that will always keep down the number of points, while also only eliminating the points that will change the line the least. topjson.simplify does this already, but only for svg multipolygons I think.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Simplify.js](http://mourner.github.io/simplify-js/)?  It does exactly this.

Comment: Yes, I ended up asking a better version of this question with more details here, and resolving it:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17176562/extending-dc-js-to-add-a-simplelinechart-chart/17246584#17246584