# Extending dc.js to add a "simpleLineChart" chart

Tags: d3.js, simplify, crossfilter, dc.js

*edit* See here for the non-working example of what I'm trying to do: http://bl.ocks.org/elsherbini/5814788

I am using dc.js to plot data collected from bee hives at my university. I am pushing new data to the graphs on every database change (using the magic of Meteor). **When the database is over 5000 records or so, rerendering the lines gets really slow.** So I want to use simplify.js to preprocess the lines before rendering. To see what I'm talking about, go to http://datacomb.meteor.com/. The page freezes after a couple of seconds, so be warned.

I have started to extend dc.js with a `simpleLineChart`, which would inherit from the existing `dc.lineChart` object/function. Here is what I have so far:

```
dc.simpleLineChart = function(parent, chartGroup) {
    var _chart = dc.lineChart(),
        _tolerance = 1,
        _highQuality = false,
        _helperDataArray;

    _chart.tolerance = function (_) {
        if (!arguments.length) return _tolerance;
        _tolerance = _;
        return _chart;
    };

    _chart.highQuality = function (_) {
        if (!arguments.length) return _highQuality;
        _highQuality = _;
        return _chart;
    };

    return _chart.anchor(parent, chartGroup);
}
```

simplify.js takes in an array of data, a `tolerance`, and a boolean `highQuality`, and returns a new array with fewer elements based on it's simplification algorithm.

dc.js uses crossfilter.js. dc.js charts are associated with a particular crossfilter dimension and group. Eventually, it uses the data from `someGroup().all()` as the data to pass to a `d3.svg.line().` **I can't find where this is happening in the dc.js source**, but this is where I need to intervene. I want to find this method, and override it in the `dc.simpleLineChart` object that I am making.

I was thinking something like

```
_chart.theMethodINeedToOverride = function(){
    var helperDataArray = theChartGroup().all().map(function(d) { return {
        x: _chart.keyAccessor()(d), 
        y: _chart.valueAccessor()(d)};})

    var simplifiedData = simplify(helperDataArray, _tolerance, _highQuality)

    g.datum(simplifiedData); // I know I'm binding some data at some point
                             // I'm just not sure to what or when
}
```

Can anyone help me either identify which method I need to override, or even better, show me how to do so?

dc.js source: https://github.com/NickQiZhu/dc.js/blob/master/dc.js

*edit:*

I think I may have found the function I need to override. The original function is

```
function createGrouping(stackedCssClass, group) {
    var g = _chart.chartBodyG().select("g." + stackedCssClass);

    if (g.empty())
        g = _chart.chartBodyG().append("g").attr("class", stackedCssClass);

    g.datum(group.all());

    return g;
}
```

And I have tried to override it like so

```
function createGrouping(stackedCssClass, group) {
    var g = _chart.chartBodyG().select("g." + stackedCssClass);

    if (g.empty())
        g = _chart.chartBodyG().append("g").attr("class", stackedCssClass);

    var helperDataArray = group().all().map(function(d) { return {
        x: _chart.keyAccessor()(d), 
        y: _chart.valueAccessor()(d)};})

    var simplifiedData = simplify(helperDataArray, _tolerance, _highQuality)

    g.datum(simplifiedData);

    return g;
}
```

However, when I make a simpleLineChart, it is just a linechart with a `tolerance()` and `highQuality()` method. See here: http://bl.ocks.org/elsherbini/5814788

Comment: Still think you should bin the data more before plotting! The chart is only a couple of hundred px wide; there isn't any reason to plot a line chart with thousands of points. Rasterizing the svg to display on a monitor is binning the data already.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "binning the data." I think the naive solution would be to plot every nth point, but this fails when the dataset gets really large, because eventually there would be something like 5 points per day, and they wouldn't reflect the shape of the line before binning necessarily. And if you meant binning by frequency, I want to end up with a line chart, rather than a histogram. See http://mourner.github.io/simplify-js/ to see what I have in mind. 70,000 some points reduced to less than a hundred, still retaining the shape.

Comment: group it by day, hour, or some other sliding scale. I'm assuming this is the same project (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16924767/simplifying-a-line-before-rendering-on-chart-in-d3)? Instead of trying to draw 70,000 lines representing 5 min intervals, find the average daily value and plot that.

Comment: Got it. This is essentially plotting only every 12th point (hourly) or some average of every 288 points (daily). This loses a lot of resolution. In the example linked above, they reduced 70,000 some points to 154 (479 times), but the line looks essentially the same. If they instead plotted every 479th point, it would look a lot different, and cost pretty much the same computationally to render.

Comment: See what I mean here: http://tributary.io/inlet/5798836. The top is simplified the cool way, the bottom the less cool way.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I pretty much did what I set out to do.
http://bl.ocks.org/elsherbini/5814788

The key was to not only modify the `createGrouping` function, but also the `lineY` function in the code. (`lineY` gets set to tell the `d3.svg.line()` instance how to set the y value of a given point `d`)

I changed it to

```
var lineY = function(d, dataIndex, groupIndex) {
    return _chart.y()(_chart.valueAccessor()(d));
};
```

The way `lineY` was written before, it was looking up the y value in an array, rather than using the data bound to the group element. This array had it's data set before i made my changes, so it was still using the old, pre-simplification data.